# Find the second maximum group by colume in sql

Tags: mysql

Here is my `SQL` query to find a row in `currency_price` table grouped by maximum date of inserting to table.My question is how to find the second maximum.
I mean how can I change this query to find the second maximum row in each group.

```
select symbol,currency_name,country,sell,buy
from (
    select *
    from currency_price natural
    join currency natural join users
    order by currency_id, cu_date desc,buy,sell,user_id ) x
group by currency_id
```

I know some query to find second maximum but all does not take me to my answer.

Comment: use "limit 1,1" in query

Comment: Your query is not correct, could you please show your correct sql?

Comment: i have some currency id in my table.with this query i grouped them by id and then find each currency id with maximum date of insert.so the answer of this query show me for each currency id just one row.but i need the second for comparison of the price now and before for each currency

Comment: How about posting some sample data and your desired result?

Comment: Your SQL should result in error, please paste structure of your above 3 tables

Answer (score 1):

Due the fact you are not using aggreagtion function seems  are using   group by in wrong way ..  could be that you are using group by instead of disticct .. so your query should be

```
select distinct symbol,currency_name,country,sell,buy
from (
    select *
    from currency_price natural
    join currency natural join users
    order by currency_id, cu_date desc,buy,sell,user_id ) x
```

and for obtain more then one row don't use distinct

```
select symbol,currency_name,country,sell,buy
from (
    select *
    from currency_price natural
    join currency natural join users
    order by currency_id, cu_date desc,buy,sell,user_id ) x
```

PS .. you have also a natult join  on user too  ( could be this return unexpected  result)